# How do you use php?email=# to retrieve record

Tags: php

In abc.php, i have a form whose action is xyz.php. I want `$email=$POST['txtEmail']` to be used in xyz.php

To do that, I typed: `<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="xyz.php?<?php $email=$_POST['txtEmail']; ?>">`

Is this the correct way to do it?

**EDIT**

abc.php

```
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="xyz.php">
     <input name="txtEmail" type="text" size="30" />
     <input type="submit" name="Submit2" value="Submit" />
 </form>
```

xyz.php

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="def.php">
   <input type="text" name="txtAns" />                                                
   <input type="hidden" name="txtEmail" id="txtEmail" value="<?php echo $_POST['txtEmail']; ?>" />
  <input type="submit" name="submitEmail" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

def.php

```
$email=$_POST['txtEmail'];
```

Comment: I'm not even sure how one could interpret that as being correct...

Comment: so, what is the right way to do it?

Comment: It seems you have mix between $_POST and $_GET, what actually you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited**

In abc.php:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="xyz.php">
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
</form>
```

In xyz.php

```
<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="def.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>" />
</form>
```

In def.php

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

Is that what you're after?

Comment: I did that in abc.php. I want $email to be used in 2 pages say, xyz.php and def.php

Comment: You want the form to be posted to two pages? I'm afraid that won't happen. The best thing you can do is put `header('Location: xyz.php?email=' . urlencode($_POST['email']));`, in abc.php, then in xyz.php: $email = urldecode($_POST['email');`. This will cause an immediate redirect once the form has been submitted to abc.php

Comment: okay, let me clarify my question. abc.php has a form. It's action is xyz.php. xyz.php also has a form whose action is def.php. In xyz.php, it takes input from abc.php which is $email.

Comment: I want $email to be used in def.php, based on form action in xyz.php. not header.

Comment: yes. but def.php isn't checking from database where Email=$email

Comment: What? There's no mention of database involvement in your question, you asked how to get a value from one page to another using a form in each page. The answer above does exactly that.

Comment: Well, I have database. and I also tried your codes above. It won't work.

Comment: I've just tried it myself and it works perfectly. Please copy and paste the code into the files exactly as it's described in the answer above. Also make sure your question is complete next time.

Comment: As stated before that works perfectly. `echo $_POST['txtEmail'];` in def.php prints out the email address that was chosen in the first form, which is correct.

Comment: Upto this point of getting $email from one form to another is correct right?

Comment: Yes, the question you have asked has been answered. Please accept the answer as correct.

Comment: echo $_POST['txtEmail']; printed my email in def.php. That's what I wanted. Thanks for helping me till that point. I'll handle the database stuff myself. :)